# Mongo + Rails $or query with multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo record with following structure:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId(..)
  first_name:
  last_name:
  address: {
    street1:
    street2:
    city:
  }
}
```

I need to find records having `street1` `not null` `$or` `street2` `not null`.
I have 2 records having `street1` `not null` and 2 records having `street2` `not null`.
Need single query which will return all 4 records.

How do I merge there two queries into one

```
pry(main)> User.where(:'address.street1'.ne => nil)
=> 2
pry(main)> User.where(:'address.street2'.ne => nil)
=> 2
```

Expected:
Single query which will return all 4 records.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using:

```
User.where(:$or => [{:'address.street1'.ne => nil}, {:'address.street2'.ne => nil}])
```